# Azure Function Blob trigger not responding to manual import

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to get the Azure function to trigger when a blob file is uploaded. The function was deployed from an azure DevOps release.

Azure deploy steps (shows most relevant information):

[image: DevOps deploy steps]

Storage account:
- has a folder [blob folder]  where I upload files to.

Azure function code:

```
public async static Task Run([BlobTrigger("[blob folder]/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
  // any breakpoint here is never hit.
}
```

function.json:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.24",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "path": "[blob folder]/{name}",
      "name": "myBlob"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/[dllname].dll",
  "entryPoint": "[namespace].[function].[command]"
}
```

The storage and function are part of the same resource group. The Function app settings contains the values **AzureWebJobsDashboard** and **AzureWebJobsStorage**. I read these should be available in the function settings in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286303/azure-function-works-fine-in-visual-studio-but-is-not-being-triggered-once-publi) post. I also turned off the Function setting "Always On" for the function, and made sure the function is running.

Running and debugging the function locally (with the Azure storage emulator and storage explorer) works fine. The function is triggered after I upload a file to the blob folder.

In Azure, it seems like nothing happens. I'm not super familiar with the Azure environment, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the [FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Function-Runtime-Versioning) setting in the application settings. I needed to update this setting to the correct version.

I managed to get the debugging running using [Jason Robert's blog post](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Remote-Debugging-Azure-Functions-V2-The-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-No-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-this-document) and debug the trigger event of my function.